# node.js - bcrypt.compare() is not working in async function

Tags: node.js, async-await, passport.js, bcrypt

Here is my code:

```
async function(account, pwd, done) {
        Member.findOne({ account: account }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            } else if (await bcrypt.compare(pwd, user.pwd)) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
            }

        });
    }
```

But when I run the server, I always get this error:

```
E:\nodeJS\Express\server\routes\api\login.js:22
            } else if (await bcrypt.compare(pwd, user.pwd)) {        
                             ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

bcrypt.compareSync(rawPassword, hashedPassword);
```

compareSync works for async functions without an await.

Comment: I've used this in my past projects and it has worked ^^

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I just solved this problem, but not using this method you provided. I will make a comment to state my method below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Just change the location of `async`.
Here is the solution:

```
function(account, pwd, done) {
        Member.findOne({ account: account }, async(err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            } else if (await bcrypt.compare(pwd, user.pwd)) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
            }

        });
    }
```

Put `async` in front of `(err, user) =>......`

Thank again for those who spend time on my question!